# How to put an object into an array?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, arrays, object, segue

maybe somebody can help me. I just don't get my mistake. I have a simple App with a tableView. In that table View are a lot of different things listed. When the user clicks on a cell he gets to a ViewController where he can See different pictures and explanations for his chosen cell ( for instance he clicks on the cell with the name Dog init. So he would see pictures and explanation for dogs). For every "thing" i have created an own class. So for example I have the class dogs, cats, cars... . In every Class I have created an array with pictures and text files which is returned to the TableViewController.

I have created different Class Objects in the TableViewController :

```
 #import "IphoneTabelle.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Dogs.h"
#import "Cats.h"

@interface IphoneTabelle ()


@end


@implementation IphoneTabelle


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    /
    //create dog object for array
    Dogs *dogClass = [[WLAN alloc]init];
    _createdClassObjectArrayPics = dogClass.picsDogs;
    _createdClassObjectArrayText = dogClass.textDogs;



    //Cat objects created for array

    Cats *catClass = [[ControlCenter alloc]init];
    _createdClassObjectArrayPics = catClass.picsCats;
    _createdClassObjectArrayText = catClass.textCats;


    //create objects if they dont exists
    if (!_objects ){
        _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }


    //put the class-objects array in objects array
    [_objects addObject:NSStringFromClass([dogClass class])];

    [_objects addObject:NSStringFromClass([catClass class])];
```

So wenn the user clicks on a Cell a segue is used. The Pictures and the texts are supposed to be put into an array from the ViewController.h . Those arrays are used to show the Pictures and texts in the ViewController.

segue Code

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    ViewController *sendDataToViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;
    NSArray *picturesArrayTableView = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    NSArray *texteArrayTableView = [[NSArray alloc]init];


    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"show"]){


        picturesArrayTableView = _createdClassObjectArrayPics[indexPath.row];
        texteArrayTableView =  _createdClassObjectArrayText[indexPath.row];


   //picsArray and textsArray are declared in ViewController.H file
        sendDataToViewController.picsArray= picturesArrayTableView;
        sendDataToViewController.textsArray = texteArrayTableView;



    }
```

So When the User clicks on the Cell I'll get an error every time :
**'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10becc198'**

Somehow the data from the pictures and the texts are not in the picturesArrayTableView and texteArrayTableView.

How can I get work with just one segue? I don't want to make a segue for every cell/object. That way would work indeed, but it is really annoying and messy to create hundreds of segues.

I hope I could clarify my question somehow.

Comment: what does this dogClass.picsDogs return ?

Comment: `_createdClassObjectArrayPics`  will have last added object always. In your case it is catClass.picsCats.

Comment: The different classes are returning an array for the pictures and an array for the texts.

Answer (score 0):

**Create Dog class as follow:**

```
@interface Dog : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *pics;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *texts;


@end
```

**Creating objects and adding it into the array**

```
Dog *dogObject=[[Dog alloc]init];

dogObject.pics = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
dogObject.texts = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

//Add some Pics to dog
[dogObject.pics addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dog.png"]];
//or you can add objects from another array

//Add Text for that pic
[dogObject.texts addObject:@"Cute Dog"];

//Note that Pics and text array will have same count



//create objects if they dont exists
if (!arrObject ){
    arrObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

[arrObject addObject:dogObject];
```

**When you tap table**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Show" sender:indexPath];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

     if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Show"])
     {
        //getting indexpath for selected Item
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = (NSIndexPath *)sender;
        id selectedObject=[arrObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        //getting View Controller
        ViewController *sendDataToViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        //pass selected item to destingation View Controller
        sendDataToViewController.selectedItem = selectedObject;
     }


}
```

Catch the passed object in your detail view controller. To do so you need to create Property in Detail ViewController class.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id selectedItem;
```

Now you can access this object's photos and texts.

```
        if ([selectedItem isKindOfClass:[Dog class]])
         {
             // we got the dog object
             Dog *dogObject =(Dog *)selectedItem;

             //access Pics Like follow

             UIImage *image = [dogObject.pics objectAtIndex:0];
             NSString *text = [dogObject.texts objectAtIndex:0];

         }
         else [selectedItem isKindOfClass:[Cat class]]
         {
             //Same above Thing
         }
```

This is just an example, you can utilize things as you wish.

Comment: So i've tried to implement that into my code. When I am running the code in the simulator I am getting the following error :

Comment: 2016-10-20 19:37:45.763 HowToIphone[5898:4944908] the objects in _objects are (
    "<WLAN: 0x600000246e10>",
    "<ControlCenter: 0x608000442d30>"
)
2016-10-20 19:37:45.770 HowToIphone[5898:4944908] -[WLAN isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000246e10

I thought maybe there is a problem with the array of objects, thats why the log statement. I  have the the feeling that the error is b/c the object array doesn't know what to write into the cellLables. But maybe I am totally wrong and the mistake is somewhere else